# How to use loop with geom_vline and facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, geom-vline

I have data similar to the one I've created below:

```
set.seed(42)
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2012-08-01"), as.Date("2014-08-30"), "day")
n <- length(dates)
dat <- data.frame(date = dates,
                  category = rep(LETTERS[1:4], n/2),
                  daily_count = sample(18:100, n, replace=TRUE))

#following to be used for creating dotted lines; highlighting a certain point for each category
point_dates <- sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2012-08-01"), as.Date("2014-08-30"), "month"),4)
category_name <- list("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

I am creating a boxplot for each category using `facet_wrap`, and `point_dates` are important for me as they shows the point of interest in each boxplot. This is how I am creating the plot:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = daily_count,
                   x = yearmonth(date),
                   group = paste(yearmonth(date), category),
                   fill = category)) +
  labs(x = 'Month & Year',
       y = 'Count',
       fill = "Category") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10),
        legend.position="none") +
  geom_vline(xintercept =  lubridate::ymd("2013-08-23"), linetype=1, colour="red", size = 0.5)+
  
  sapply(point_dates[[1]], function(xint) geom_vline(data=filter(dat, 
  category==category_name[[1]]),aes(xintercept = xint),
  linetype=3, colour="black", size = 1))+
  
  sapply(point_dates[[2]], function(xint) geom_vline(data=filter(dat, 
  category==category_name[[2]]),aes(xintercept = xint),
  linetype=3, colour="black", size = 1))+
  
  sapply(point_dates[[3]], function(xint) geom_vline(data=filter(dat, 
  category==category_name[[3]]),aes(xintercept = xint),
  linetype=3, colour="black", size = 1))+
  
  sapply(point_dates[[4]], function(xint) geom_vline(data=filter(dat, 
  category==category_name[[4]]),aes(xintercept = xint),
  linetype=3, colour="black", size = 1))+
  
  facet_wrap(~category, nrow = 2)
```

And this is the output of the code:
[image]
The plot is being created just fine. My question is, is there any better way (loop may be?) that would help me get rid of writing `sapply` multiple times. Because the number of categories may change (increase/decrease), that would be to change the code everytime.

Any guidance please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best way, but you could do all of them in one go using `map2` from `tidyr`. This would save you time from having to write out individual `sapply`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = daily_count,
                   x = yearmonth(date),
                   group = paste(yearmonth(date), category),
                   fill = category)) +
  labs(x = 'Month & Year',
       y = 'Count',
       fill = "Category") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10),
        legend.position="none") +
  geom_vline(xintercept =  lubridate::ymd("2013-08-23"), 
             linetype=1, colour="red", size = 0.5)+
  map2(point_dates, category_name, 
       ~geom_vline(data=filter(dat, category==.y),
                   aes(xintercept = .x),
                   linetype=3, colour="black", size = 1))+
  facet_wrap(~category, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone. I love SO, always find the solutions and the best of people. All answers were right ones, I wish I could choose them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to iterate the calls to `sapply()`:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = daily_count,
                   x = yearmonth(date),
                   group = paste(yearmonth(date), category),
                   fill = category)) +
  labs(x = 'Month & Year',
       y = 'Count',
       fill = "Category") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10),
        legend.position="none") +
  geom_vline(xintercept =  lubridate::ymd("2013-08-23"), linetype=1, colour="red", size = 0.5)+
  
  map(seq_along(unique(dat$category)), ~sapply(point_dates[[.]], function(xint) geom_vline(data=filter(dat, 
  category==category_name[[.]]),aes(xintercept = xint),
  linetype=3, colour="black", size = 1))) +

  facet_wrap(~category, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got it correct, you have already defined the dates for each group. So make the first plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)

g = ggplot(dat) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = daily_count,
                   x = yearmonth(date),
                   group = paste(yearmonth(date), category),
                   fill = category)) +
  labs(x = 'Month & Year',
       y = 'Count',
       fill = "Category") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10),
        legend.position="none") +
  geom_vline(xintercept =  lubridate::ymd("2013-08-23"), linetype=1, colour="red", size = 0.5)+ 
  facet_wrap(~category, nrow = 2)
```

You just need to provide a new data frame and call geom_vline:

```
tmp = data.frame(category=unlist(category_name),date=point_dates)

g + geom_vline(data=tmp,aes(xintercept = date),
linetype=3, colour="black", size = 1)
```

[image]